# How to make arrow in specific place

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I have code like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

b = 2.8977685 * (10 ** -3)

k_range = [i for i in range(3500, 5500)]
results = [b/i for i in range(3500, 5500)]

plt.plot(results, k_range)
plt.show()
```

[image: my plot]

And now how can I draw arron to find result in K = 4800

Comment: See the docs for the arrow function: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something like this?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b = 2.8977685 * (10 ** -3)

k_range = [i for i in range(3500, 5500)]
results = [b/i for i in range(3500, 5500)]

k = np.array(k_range)
i = np.where(k==4800)

r=np.array(results)
r[i]

plt.plot(results, k_range, marker='x', markevery=[i[0][0]], markeredgecolor='r')
ax = plt.gcf().gca()
ax.annotate("", xy=(r[i], 4800), xytext=(r[i], 4400), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `matplotlib.pyplot.arrow()`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

b = 2.8977685 * (10 ** -3)

k_range = [i for i in range(3500, 5500)]
results = [b/i for i in range(3500, 5500)]

plt.plot(results, k_range)
plt.arrow(6E-7, 4000, 8E-8, 200, ec='red', width = 5E-12, head_width=1E-8)
plt.show()
```